# Android ID, IMEI and MAC tracking from Analytics SDK

Tags: macos, sdk, tracking, imei

We are releasing our Android app in Google and Non Google play store.

Does Firebase analytics supports tracking of  Android ID, IMEI and MAC?

If we use analytics SDK, which support both Google Advertising identifier and also Android ID alongwith IMEI/MAC tracking, will our app be banned from release?
And How should we integrate Firebase or any other SDK if non-Google Play store does not support Google Advertising Identifier?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics captures the Advertising Identifier on Google Play devices, but this is not the primary user key. Instead, a unique id is generated for each instance of the app on a device, and that behavior is consistent across Google Play and non-Google Play devices.